# Laravel seeder raise 'Column not found' about dummy column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-seeding

I have a User model with custom attribute,
attribute `name` that concatenate `firstName` and `lastName`:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['firstName', 'lastName'];

    protected $appends = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function getNameAttribute(){
        return $this->attributes['firstName'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['lastName'];
    }
}
```

Also I have a many to many relation to `Group` model.

The problem is, when I try to do seeding:

```
factory(App\Group::class, 30)
    ->create()
    ->each(function ($group) {
        $group->users()->createMany(factory(App\User::class, 3)->make()->toArray());
    });
```

I get exception:

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'
```

My Factory:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
        'firstName' => $faker->firstName,
        'lastName' => $faker->lastName,
   ];
});
```

When I comment `name` attribute, it works fine.
Thanks.

Comment: please share your UserFactory

Comment: did you try put 'name' to `$fillable`?

Comment: he can't put 'name' in fillable, there is no real column named 'name' @Wiguna R

Comment: Right. My fault i don't really know what `$appends` is. I read some of articles with my native language, says that if Accessor method must be camelCase and `$appends` properties must be snake_case which is what OP did. [source](https://medium.com/laravel-web-id/kapan-menggunakan-magic-property-appends-di-laravel-cd4c1173a4d)

Comment: Hi, I have added `UserFactory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert the collection of Users to an array. This serializes the models and in your case you are appending the `name` attribute which is an accessor and doesn't exist.

When it comes to seeding your models are unguarded already so fillable/guarded isn't in play.

Since you have model instances (that have not been saved yet) that you want to add to the relationship you should be using `saveMany` instead of `createMany`.

```
$group->users()->saveMany(factory(App\User::class, 3)->make());
```

This way you are not serializing the model to an array which would add the `name` field which you don't want to try and save since that field is 'virtual'.

Though I am not entirely sure how you setup this relationship.